# Modelling a flow due to an oscillating hemisphere?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator, computational-physics, flow

Say I have a long cylinder filled with air, closed at one end and open at the other. Now say I place a compressible hemisphere at the closed end and make it oscillate (compression and expansion of the non-flat surface region). The oscillations will generate a flow field. How would I model this situation computationally so that I could predict the force generated at the open end of the cylinder due to the intensity of oscillations of the hemisphere?

Comment: Seems to me you'd be generating sound waves: that's what an oscillating surface 'banging' against an elastic medium (like air) does.